# Count empty input field[]?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="uploadimages">
    <li><input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="upload1"/></li>
    <li><input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="upload2"/></li>
    <li><input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="upload3"/></li>
    <li><input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="upload4"/></li>
</ul>
```

How to count how many empty input(type="file") fields inside the `<ul>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with your example

```
<ul id="uploadimages">
    <li><input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="upload1"/></li>
    <li><input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="upload2"/></li>
    <li><input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="upload3"/></li>
    <li><input type="file" name="gallery[]" id="upload4"/></li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="click" class="count"/>
```

Script in document.ready

```
$(".count").click(function(){
var count = $('#uploadimages input:file[value=""]').length
alert(count);

})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#uploadimages input:file[value=""]').length
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted approach of Murtaza unfortunatelly doesn't work for me. I don't know why. https://jsfiddle.net/7vLrhqyw/

This works:

```
$(".count").click(function () {
    var count=0;
    $('#uploadimages input:file').each(function(){
       if($(this).val()=="")count++; 
    });
    alert(count);

});
```